# mysql data read returning 0 rows from class

Tags: c#, mysql, mysqldatareader

I am implementing a database manager class within my app, mainly  because there are 3 databases to connect to one being a local one.

However the return function isn't working, I know the query brings back rows but when it is returned by the class it has 0.  What am I missing?

```
public MySqlDataReader localfetchrows(string query, List<MySqlParameter> dbparams = null)
    {
        using (var conn = connectLocal())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting local : " + conn.ServerVersion);
            MySqlCommand sql = conn.CreateCommand();
            sql.CommandText = query;
            if (dbparams != null)
            {
                if (dbparams.Count > 0)
                {
                    sql.Parameters.AddRange(dbparams.ToArray());
                }
            }
            MySqlDataReader reader = sql.ExecuteReader();
            Console.WriteLine("Reading data : " + reader.HasRows + reader.FieldCount);
            return reader;
            /*
            using (MySqlCommand sql = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                sql.CommandText = query;
                if (dbparams != null)
                {
                    if (dbparams.Count > 0)
                    {
                        sql.Parameters.AddRange(dbparams.ToArray());
                    }
                }

                MySqlDataReader reader = sql.ExecuteReader();
                Console.WriteLine("Reading data : " + reader.HasRows + reader.FieldCount);

                sql.Parameters.Clear();
                return reader;
            }*/
        }

    }
```

And the code to get the results

```
query = @"SELECT jobtypeid, title FROM jobtypes WHERE active = 'Y' ORDER BY title ASC";
            //parentfrm.jobtypes = db.localfetchrows(query);
            var rows = db.localfetchrows(query);
            Console.WriteLine("Reading data : " + rows.HasRows + rows.FieldCount);
            while (rows.Read()){

            }
```

These scripts return the following :

```
Connecting local : 5.5.16
Reading data : True2
Reading data : False0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`using (var conn = connectLocal())`

You're placing the connection inside a using statement, thus closing and disposing the connection after you get to this line:

```
return reader;
```

In other words, when the caller gets the `reader` back, you've closed the database connection and can't fetch the rows. The connection have to be open while the rows are read.

Answer (score 2):

You want to return a `DataReader` from within a `using-statement` which will close the underlying connection implicitely.

Instead of returning the `DataReader` i would recommend following pattern. You could yield [`IEnumerable<IDatarecord>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.aspx).

```
public IEnumerable<IDataRecord> localfetchrows(string query, List<MySqlParameter> dbparams = null)
{
    using (var conn = connectLocal())
    {
        MySqlCommand sql = conn.CreateCommand();
        sql.CommandText = query;
        if (dbparams != null)
        {
            if (dbparams.Count > 0)
            {
                sql.Parameters.AddRange(dbparams.ToArray());
            }
        }

        conn.Open();
        using (IDataReader rdr = sql.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                yield return (IDataRecord)rdr;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it for example in this way:

```
var records = localfetchrows(query);
foreach (var rec in records.Take(10))
{ 
     Console.WriteLine("Reading data : " + rec.FieldCount);
}
```

So you don't need to load all into memory just to take a small subset of it.

Answer (score 1):

You create the reader inside a MySqlConnection using block, when exiting from that block your reader has no connection to use.

A possible solution, but less efficient, is to use the Fill method to get back a dataset. 
This is not only less efficient, but, if you need to process the datarows, you will find yourself looping again on the rows

```
public DataSet localfetchrows(string query, List<MySqlParameter> dbparams = null) 
{ 
    DataSet ds;
    using (var conn = connectLocal()) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting local : " + conn.ServerVersion); 
        MySqlCommand sql = conn.CreateCommand(); 
        sql.CommandText = query; 
        if (dbparams != null) 
        { 
            if (dbparams.Count > 0) 
            { 
                sql.Parameters.AddRange(dbparams.ToArray()); 
            } 
        } 
        MySqlDataReader reader = sql.ExecuteReader(); 
        Console.WriteLine("Reading data : " + reader.HasRows + reader.FieldCount); 
        reader.Fill(ds);
        return ds; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are disposing of the connection before using the reader. Try disposing of the connection only after you are done with the reader.